# Unexpected errors on usaco transform problem

Tags: python

I've been stuck on this problem for a while, and can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Feel free to read the whole problem description at https://mdwgti16.github.io/usaco%20training/transformations/

I pretty much simulated every aspect of the problem, and I believe all of my functions are working properly, yet my results don't match what's correct.

Something very strange that's happened is my outputs will change when I add certain print statements, which doesn't seem like it should be possible.

```
def rotate(grid):
    new = grid.copy()
    l, r = 0, len(grid) - 1
    while l < r:
        for i in range(r - l):
            top, bottom = l, r

            # save the topleft
            topLeft = grid[top][l + i]

            # move bottom left into top left
            new[top][l + i] = grid[bottom - i][l]

            # move bottom right into bottom left
            new[bottom - i][l] = grid[bottom][r - i]

            # move top right into bottom right
            new[bottom][r - i] = grid[top + i][r]

            # move top left into top right
            new[top + i][r] = topLeft
        r -= 1
        l += 1
    return new

# reverse each row individually
def reflect(grid):
    new = []
    rows = len(grid)
    for i in range(rows):
        new.append(grid[i][::-1])
    return new

with open('transform.in', 'r') as fin, open('transform.out', 'w') as fout:
    n = int(fin.readline().strip())
    before = [list(fin.readline().strip()) for _ in range(n)]
    after = [list(fin.readline().strip()) for _ in range(n)]

    if after == rotate(before):
        print('1')
        fout.write("1\n")
    elif after == rotate(rotate(before)):
        print('2')
        fout.write("2\n")
    elif after == rotate(rotate(rotate(before))):
        print('3')
        fout.write("3\n")
    elif after == reflect(before):
        print('4')
        fout.write("4\n")
    elif (after == rotate(reflect(before)) or
        after == rotate(rotate(reflect(before))) or
        after == rotate(rotate(rotate(reflect(before))))):
        print('5')
        fout.write("5\n")
    elif after==before:
        print('6')
        fout.write("6\n")
    else:
        print('7')
        fout.write("7\n")
```

Comment: I have to say that your question isn't self contained, you ask the viewer to visit an external site to understand the problem. Without knowing the context, it is very hard to judge the purpose of your code. And external sites can be shutdown and will be shutdown. It is a matter of time. When that happens nobody will know what your code is about.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76723965/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.